# jquery including post request (exchanging vars)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm a little stuck with a jQuery. At the moment my function looks like this.

```
$(function(){
    $(".url2").keyup(validNum).blur(validNum);

    function validNum() {

    var initVal = $(this).val();
    outputVal = initVal.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?[0-9A-Za-z-]{2,50}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}([\/\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#]){0,250}(\s){1}$/ 
,"http://my.site/ref.php?id=<?php $code = unqiue-ref-id(); echo $unqiue-ref-id;?>");   
    if (initVal != outputVal) {
        $(this).val(outputVal);
        return false;

        }}

});
```

So right now it rewrites a user typed url (in a textarea) to a redirection link with my own url (e.g. `my.site?ref.php?id=unique12`. What I need exactly is a POST Request to a php file (code below) where the valid user-url is given to the php file as a var and then the php file should give back a var with the generated unique unique-ref-id. I do of course know that the code above isn't working like that, it only shows how the final result should look like. The php file wich generates the unique-ref-id looks like this.

```
 function unqiue-ref-id() {
    $unqiue-ref-id = "";
    $lenght=4;
    $string="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";

    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

    for ($i=1; $i <= $lenght; $i++) {
        $shorturl .= substr($string, mt_rand(0,strlen($string)-1), 1);
    }
    return $unqiue-ref-id;

}


$user-url = // var send from jquery


do{
  $unqiue-ref-id = unqiue-ref-id();
} while(in_array($unqiue-ref-id, $result));

// var send back to jquery function => final results of do function above

// Here i add the $user-url and $unique-ref-id to datebase (Dont need code for that)


?>
```

Would be so great if someone can help me out with that. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the POST jQuery's method. Here's an example

```
$.post('URL-TO-POST-DATA', {'parameter1': 'value', 'parameter2': 'value'}, function(data_received){
/** Here goes your callback function **/ alert(data_received);
});
```

[More information about POST method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Don't forget one thing. jQuery will not receive nothing if you don't use echo on PHP (instead of return). **You MUST use echo in PHP, don't forget it.**